# How to output hostname with log4j in Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, log4j

My codes and config are as follows. It works for localhost mode but not for cluster when I submit my spark job to yarn cluster.

```
System.setProperty("hostName", InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName());

log4j.rootCategory=INFO, CONSOLE
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.target=System.err
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=${hostName} %d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n
```

Someone can help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, you do not actually use 'logger', you have to add this:

```
logger.info(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName())
```

Second, you'd better analyze logs in $SPARK_HOME$/logs folder.